# What is the meaning of the % character in vim?

Tags: vim

The vim [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) page provides the following description for search and replace:

> ```
> :%s/foo/bar/g
> ```
>
> Find each occurrence of 'foo' (in all lines), and replace it with 'bar'.
>
> ```
> :s/foo/bar/g
> ```
>
> Find each occurrence of 'foo' (in the current line only), and replace it with 'bar'.
>
> ...

I can see that the the `%` character causes the whole buffer to be searched.

What is the meaning of the `%` character in vim?  Is it a variable that refers to the current buffer?

Comment: `%` is a shorter way of writing `1,$`, i.e. from the first line to the last.

Comment: What about trying the documentation next time? `:help :%`.

Comment: The first thing I tried was `:help %`.  I didn't know that I should have tried `:help :%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Here's how you would have found the information:

Look up the command: `:help :substitute`

> ```
>   :[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
> ```

Ah, the stuff in front is called *range*. Further down, there's a link to it:

> ```
>       Also see |cmdline-ranges|.
> ```

(`:help [range]` would have also taken you to it.) And that explains the meaning of `%`, as well as the help keyword for direct access.

```
%       equal to 1,$ (the entire file)        *:%*
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips navigating the help as well.  Hopefully, next time I forget the command I can use the online help to remind me now rather than google.